# How can I add a Ender Dragon in Minecraft modding?

Tags: eclipse, minecraft

I have been looking around the Internet, and no one seems to know (or care) about my question :P. I would like to know how to add a Ender Dragon mob into Minecraft. I am using Eclipse, and Youth Digital software. If you don't know what that is, just give me something to copy and paste. I'm pretty noob-ish at coding at stuff, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need to watch a few more tutorials and understand more of the basics such as item creation. You should also have a look to see the basic principles of **Java**. Stack Overflow is a great place to get advice on specific problems but I am afraid that they do not like broader problems such as the one you present here.

From your question I assume you are asking how to "spawn" in the Ender Dragon rather than "add it". For this you will need to place this snippet in a [method linked to an event handler](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/intro/):

```
EntityDragon dragon = new EntityDragon(worldIn);
worldIn.spawnEntity(dragon);
```

where `worldIn` is the world argument from the method.

However, I suggest that you watch more tutorials on YT to get the basics, then have a look at other peoples' mod code on Github.

(Quark is a great example of some simple modding mechanics, so I suggest you trawl its source code -> https://github.com/Vazkii/Quark/tree/master/src/main/java/vazkii/quark)

Comment: I actually meant instantiate it, because it's minecraft modding, but maybe I can find it on your website link.